# Why is JUnit 4 test outcome in Eclipse dependent on previous outcome of mvn test?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, maven, junit

I am running Eclipse 4.4.1 with JUnit 4.12 as a Maven dependency (scope = test). I'm running the tests both with Eclipse and with Maven.

I have a project with a main class, Corpus2Json, which I would like to test. I noticed that unit tests weren't failing when I expected them to, so I cut it down to the most basic test which should fail.

```
package path.to.package;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class Corpus2JsonTest {
  @Test
  public void test() {
    fail();
  }

}
```

It didn't fail in Eclipse, but it did in Maven. I checked again in Eclipse and it failed. I removed the `fail()` line and the test still failed in Eclipse.

So I created a new test class with identical code to the above except named Corpus2JsonsTest, and it failed as expected in Eclipse. I removed `fail()`, and it no longer failed. Once I ran `mvn test`, Eclipse began only returning the result of the previous Maven test.

There appears to be behavior that makes it so when Eclipse runs the test, it only has the result of the latest Maven test. Unless the test file did not exist since the previous Maven test, in which case it acts normally.

Comment: So is it not behaving in Maven, or not behaving in Eclipse? Can you reproduce it *without* Maven being involved?

Comment: @JonSkeet Actually, I think the solution may to be removing Eclipse from the situation and only doing tests with Maven. I really only care about the output of `mvn test`, but was using Eclipse since it is faster. Creating a project without Maven works as expected.

Comment: Are you using the surefire plugin?

Comment: It's in the effective pom, but I don't have it explicitly in the pom.xml.

Comment: Check `Build Automatically`.

Comment: @AlexandrM It is checked.